# Slack Team for Project Managers who want to Network, Mentor, etc

Tags: communication, communication-management

I searched a lot and couldn't find an answer to this anywhere - I wanted to know if there were any Slack Teams that have been created specifically for Project Managers to network, find mentors, discuss certifications, methodologies, share conferences/events that offer CE credits, etc. Does anyone know of one? I have created my own but would rather join one that's already off the ground. Thanks in advance for any direction you can offer.

Comment: FYI - in case anybody else wants to learn more about it: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218130338-Slack-for-project-management

Comment: While this is an interesting topic, it is really a request for a link to off-site resources. That's a close reason on PMSE, and on most stacks. I won't downvote it, as I think it's a reasonable question, but will have to vote to close as it's not on topic per our help center guidelines.

Comment: Questions seeking off-site resources (as opposed to canonical answers) are not on topic per our help center guidelines. You might bring this up in chat or on meta, but it is not a question that allows for a canonical answer within the site's Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this blog post](http://blog.drift.com/the-7-best-slack-communities-for-product-managers) by Aja Frost to be very good. She recommends several, some of which are free, some of which are paid. A very good place to start.

I joined the [Mind The Product Slack](http://slack.mindtheproduct.com), which is well worth getting involved with. I'm also considering the Product Manager HQ Slack, which is a paid option.

Hope that helps! If you do join the MTP Slack, my username is `mathew`. Say hi ;)